# A basic question on limit point of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Is this the set $\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb Z^{+}\} \cup \{1+ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb Z^{+}\} \cup \{2 + \frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb Z^{+}\}$ has exactly three limit points. I think so, namely $0,1,2$.

Comment: you are correct, but what is the question?

Comment: @user64480: I just wanted to confirm that.